# Hovering over an image to make it larger doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and I'm trying to make 2 images larger when i hover over them, but it doesn't work.

```css
.imagezoom img {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 margin: 50px 5px 0px 42px;
 border-color: rgba(143, 179, 218, 0.5);
 background-size: 100%;
 background-position: center;
 }
 
.imagezoom: hover {
 background-size: 110%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="imagezoom"><img src="images/park.jpg" border="5" width="300" height="250">     
      </div>
      
      <div class="imagezoom"><img src="images/statue.jpg" border="5" width="300" height="250">     
      </div>
```

Comment: It might be useful to use some [placeholder images](https://placeholder.com/) to further illustrate your problem. Also, what have you tried so far to fix it?

Comment: the space after the colon is wrong and your imagezoom element has no background-size. its the image within. correct: `.imagezoom:hover img`

Comment: Here is the fiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/9oq6vcck/

Answer (score 1):

This code uses a placeholder image to see a result.  Also, I borrow generously from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3hWj/4/) for the css code. Note that the background image div is wrapped in an outer DIV and that is critical  to achieve the zooming effect on hover.  On hover, the outer DIV will be enlarged to accommodate the larger dimensions of the inner div with the background image.

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div.wrap {
    height: 350px;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-left:auto;width:100%;margin-right:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

div.wrap > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 33vw;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    transform: scale(1,1);
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/' center center no-repeat);
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

div.wrap:hover > div {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.10,1.10);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.10,1.10);
    transform: scale(1.10,1.10);    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="imagezoom"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" border="5" width="400" height="200"> </div>
</div>
```

View code result in "Full Page" mode for centered effect.